# How to take a picture and pass it to another page in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, camera, gallery

I'm a beginner in Cordova and I want to take a picture from camera and use it in another page called Gallery . so, i am using this below code :

```
  document.getElementById('photo').addEventListener('click',function 
        (){
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 25,
               destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
            });

    function onSuccess(imageData) {
        var image = document.getElementById('img');
        $('#imagees').append(image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,");


        console.log(imageData);
    }


    <--HTML-->
    <div id="imagees">
    <img src="" alt="" id="img" style="width: 130px; height: "/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please specify what it is you expect the code to do, and what it currently does (e.g. error messages, stack traces etc.) In it's current form it is very hard to answer your question.

Comment: i explained what i need ,when i captured photo by (cordova camera blugin),this photo append inside the div with id (imagees)